# Moving a Namespace from one org to another

Tags: managed-package, namespace, partner, dev-hub

We have a first-generation managed package that was authored on a **Partner Developer Edition** org created by a subcontractor. We have other **Developer Edition** orgs we created. One is a **Dev Hub** and we linked the namespace from the **Partner Developer Edition** org where the first-generation managed package resides. Now we want to create a second-generation managed package. We would prefer not to keep the **Partner Developer Edition** org around but *do not want to lose the namespace*.

Why do we want to get rid of that **Partner Developer Edition** org?

1. It's in Germany and we are in the US.
2. It's linked to the subcontractor's **Environment Hub**.
3. We are in the process of becoming a **Salesforce Partner** and want our own environments (and namespace).

As the namespace is linked to our **Dev Hub**, what would happen if we deactivated the original **Partner Developer Edition** org that contained the namespace? We have all the code in a Salesforce DX project in our SCM. We're not worried about other orgs having to reinstall our managed package from scratch either. The only thing we really care about is the namespace. If the Dev Hub would lose the namespace from a deactivation, can we ask Salesforce to transfer the namespace to a newly created org before deactivating the original org?

Thoughts?

Comment: You need to talk to SF support, but pretty sure you cannot move a namespace from one org to another.

Comment: I can tell you, it's not going to be easy getting support to move the namespace. However no harm is escalating and asking for it

Comment: The answer is no, review [edit namespace](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385558&type=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385558&type=1), Once a namespace prefix is created, it cannot be changed or deleted.
The workaround is to move all your code to a new Developer Organization, Even support cannot move a namespace.